# Numpy where broadcastable condition

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I have used `numpy.where()` so many times now, and I always wondered about the following statement in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html?highlight=where#numpy.where):

> x, y and condition need to be broadcastable to some shape.

I see why this is necessary for both **x** and **y**. We want to assemble the resulting array from the two, so they should be broadcastable to the same shape. However, I do not understand why this is so important for the **condition** as well. It is only the decision rule. Suppose I have the following three shapes:

```
condition = (100,)
x         = (100, 5)
y         = (100, 5)
result    = np.where(condition, x, y)
```

This results in a ValueError, because the "operands could not be broadcast together". To my understanding, this expression should work just fine, because I compose my result of both x and y which are broadcastable.

Can you help me understand why it is so important for the condition to be broadcastable along with x and y?

Comment: `where` does not automatically use the (100,) as 'row' selector.  It has to be (100,1)  to work with the others to produce a (100,5) result.

Comment: What result would you expect from the presented case? The shapes are not compatible so how would you determine what to select? Even if `condition` was of shape `(100, 1)` the only sensible thing to do is broadcast against `x` and `y` otherwise how would you determine what column to select?

Comment: @a_guest, I wrote the below answer assuming that the issue is that "condition" is a confusing name that makes it sound as if the parameter somehow behaves like a lambda function, even though it's actually just a boolean array.

Comment: @senderle How can an array behave like a lambda function? All of numpy is about arrays, so where would the notion of a lambda function even come from? I suppose I'm completely misunderstanding the question here.

Comment: @a_guest I think you're approaching the problem from the perspective of someone familiar with all the details of Python and numpy. But there are languages where similar syntax would be used to create a condition to be interpreted as a function and applied. If you're coming from one of those languages, the syntax might be hard to interpret here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition is fundamentally a boolean array, not a generic condition. You could think of it as a mask over the final broadcasted shape of `x` and `y`.

If you think of it that way, it should be clear that the mask must have the same shape, or be broadcastable to the same shape, as the final output.

To illustrate this, here's a simple example. To begin with, consider a scenario in which we have hand-defined a 3x3 mask array as our `condition`, and we pass in two 3-item arrays as `x` and `y`, shaped to broadcast appropriately:

```
condition = numpy.array([[0, 1, 1],
                         [1, 0, 1],
                         [0, 0, 1]])
ones = numpy.ones(3)
numpy.where(condition, ones[:, None], ones[None, :] + 1)
```

The result looks like this:

```
>>> numpy.where(condition, ones[:, None], ones[None, :] + 1)
array([[2., 1., 1.],
       [1., 2., 1.],
       [2., 2., 1.]])
```

Because of the broadcasting step, `x` and `y` behave as if they were defined like this:

```
>>> x
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
>>> y
array([[2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2.]])
>>> numpy.where(condition, ones[:, None], ones[None, :] + 1)
array([[2., 1., 1.],
       [1., 2., 1.],
       [2., 2., 1.]])
```

This is the fundamental behavior of `where`. The fact that you can pass in a condition like `(x > 5)` doesn't change anything about the above; `(x > 5)` becomes a boolean array, and it must have the same shape as the output, or else it must be broadcastable to that shape. Otherwise, the behavior of `where` would be ill-defined.

(By the way, I am assuming your question is not about why the shapes `(100,)`, `(100, 5)`, and `(100, 5)` aren't broadcastable; that seems to be a different question.)